# Xbox Live : DEP6953 Failed to launch remote debugger 0x800700d8

Tags: visual-studio, xbox

I get this error trying to deploy app to XBox One.  Same error trying to deploy Universal App or XBox Live app in both C++ and C#.  We've tried multiple PC's and multiple XBox One's.  A month ago, I could deploy.  Now I can't.

Targeting x64.  Running Windows 10 Creator's Update, Visual Studio 14.0.25431.01 Update 3, latest Windows SDK 10.0.15063.400

Error seems to be ERROR_EXE_MACHINE_TYPE_MISMATCH (this version is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running).

Anyone else have problems deploying to XBox One come across this error?